# Border around transparent button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to create a border with round corners on transparent button like this:

[image]

here is my transparent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>  
</selector>
```

Comment: Create a shape drawable and set as a background to button

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item><shape>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <corners 
                android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp" 
                android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" 
                android:topLeftRadius="4dp" 
                android:topRightRadius="4dp" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: replace #000000 with your own color

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDEE4.png)  This is  way to answer your question:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/white" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
 </selector>
```

Another easy way is just to use shape instead of selector, and put this code in shape:

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/white" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

</shape>
```